# Condition for a cubic equation to have a single root

Tags: roots, cubics

If a cubic equation

$$ f(x) = ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$$

Is given, what is the condition for the equation to only have a single root (counting multiple roots as one)

Comment: $\forall x: f'(x)>0$

Comment: Either you need both the turning points to lie above or below the $x$ axis, or that there are $\le$ one turning points.

Comment: @Khosrotash $-x^3$ and $ x^3 - 10x + c $ (for large enough c) both have a single (real) root

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_equation#Nature_of_the_roots

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discriminant

Comment: I think this question needs clarification. Are you asking (1) "over a field $k$ (possibly $\mathbb{R}$) what is the condition for $f(x)$ to have exactly one root (up to multiplicity) in the algebraic closure (e.g., allowing complex roots)". Or (2) "over a field $k$ what is the condition for $f(x)$ to have exactly one root (up to multiplicty) in the field $k$ (e.g., not allowing complex roots)"? These questions have significantly different answers as observed below. Moreover, are you interested only in cubics over the reals, or are you allowing any field (or even ring).

Comment: @shortmanikos: $-x^3$ has a single root  ?!

Answer (score 3):

Seeing that there are answers involving the derivative that miss the point:
It is about the Discriminant $ \Delta $. When $ \Delta \le 0 $ we have one real root.
See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_equation#Nature_of_the_roots

Answer (score 2):

$$f(x)=ax^3+bx^2+cx+d \implies f'(x)=3ax^2+2bx+c >0 \forall x \in R, ~if~ b^2 < 3 ac.$$ A monotonically increasing pr decreasing function has at most one root. Also $f(-\infty) f(\infty) <0$ $f(x)=0$ has at least  one real root by IVT. So when $b^2<3ac$, the given cubic has only one real root.

Comment: This condition is not necessary. Consider the case $$f(x)=x^3-6x^2+11x-5,$$ which is excluded by your condition.

Comment: Your are right other case for a single root is when $f_{max}f_{min} >0$. So the condition $b^2 <3ac$ is only sufficient but not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

You may look at its discriminant, which is zero if and only if the cubic equation has a multiple root.

For the equation $ax^3+ bx^2 + cx + d = 0$, the discriminant is
$$
18abcd – 4b^3d + b^2c^2 – 4ac^3 – 27a^2d^2.
$$
Therefore the condition you seek is
$$
18abcd – 4b^3d + b^2c^2 – 4ac^3 – 27a^2d^2=0.
$$

Answer (score 1):

Referring to this image of a specific cubic

[image: Cubic with gemotric parameters labeled]

The geometric parameters labeled on the diagram, in terms of the coefficients, are

$$\begin{align*}
        x_N &= \dfrac{-b}{3a} \quad \text{(abscissa of inflection point)}\\
        \\
        \delta^2 &= \dfrac{b^2-3ac}{9a^2} = x_N^2 - \dfrac{c}{3a} \quad \text{(x distance squared from inflection point to turning point)}\\
        \\
        y_N &= f(x_N) = \dfrac{2b^3}{27a^2} - \dfrac{bc}{3a} + d \quad \text{(ordinate of inflection point)}\\
        \\
        h &= 2a\delta^3 \quad \text{(y distance from inflection point to turning point)} \\
\end{align*}$$

The cubic can intersect the $x$-axis only once, in the following circumstances:

$$\begin{align*} h &= 0\\
\\
h &\in i\mathbb{R}\setminus 0\\
\\
\mathrm{or}\;\left|\dfrac{-y_N}{h}\right| &> 1 \\
\end{align*}$$

For the first two conditions, a $0$ or imaginary height, $h$, means the cubic won't have the two turning points, so it could never cross the $x$-axis more than once.

For the third condition, the ordinate of the inflection point of the cubic, $y_N$, is farther from the $x$-axis than the height, $h$, so the cubic could never cross the $x$-axis more than once.

Answer (score 1):

Consider $f(x)=ax^3+bx^2+cx+d,$ with $a>0$ WLOG. Then there is a unique solution provided that either $$f'(x)=3ax^2+2bx+c$$ has almost positive sign -- that is, when $b^2-3ac\le 0$ -- or if $b^2-3ac>0,$ then we must have that $$f(r_1)f(r_2)\ge 0,$$ where $r_1,r_2$ are the roots of the quadratic equation $f'(x)=0.$

Answer (score 0):

There is not a unique condition: as a cubic function always has at least one real root,

- either $f'(x)\le 0$,
- or $f(x)$ has a triple root, i.e. $f(x)=a(x-\alpha)^3$,
- or $f'(x)>0$, so the function has a maximum and a minimum, and both extrema have the same sign,

Comment: There is a unique condition, it doesn't involve the derivative - roots are after all the domain of algebra, not analysis :)

Comment: @shortmanikos: Yes, but this depends on what the O.P. knows of Number theory. I answered at an elementary level.